# Why is my Platform environment variable defined as 'BNB'?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi

Something, maybe the windows sdk or visual studio installer, has defined the Platform environment variable and given it the value BNB.

What does BNB mean, and why is Platform set to BNB?

Thanks.

---

I've seen this, but it doesn't answer my question:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/1d229d75-aa89-42bf-809b-ef98f42072bb

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"HP Easy Setup" ? It creates a PLATFORM environmental variable that msbuild will default to if its not directly provided, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/roboticssimulation/thread/8c158025-c48e-4ae1-9921-b8ee4f390bac/

Comment: Fyi, Similar problem with HP Win7 x64, "Platform" set to BWS

Comment: Yep, same problem here with an HP zBook - I had an environment variable of PLATFORM set to "BNB". Why on earth would HP add such an environment variable to the entire system?

Answer (score 0):

I used the EnvironmentVariables route, this worked & no reboot required