# MSBuild not building csproj

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, csproj

I have an issue building a project in Visual Studio 2010.
I'm not sure why when I build this project it tries to build as Platform="BWS".

[image: BWS platform]

I have checked all files in my project and i was unable to find any mention of BWS. It seems that due to this all my referenced projects aren't building.

Also, is it possible to reference other projects within a csproj?

Comment: Select "Configuration Manager" from the "Build" menu.  Does 'BWS' appear anywhere in the Active Solution Platform dropdown, or in the Platform column for the currently selected config/platform?

Comment: Nope. I can only see Any CPU, Mixed Platforms, x86.

Comment: + you might want to open regedit and search for 'BWS' to see if that turns up anything :)

Comment: @NickCarlson Yes! It appears that system variable Platform is set to BWS. What does it actually stand for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution:**

It appears that when you are building in VS2010 even though you have Configuration and platform Selected it for some reason still uses System Variable called "Platform" to build dependent csprojects.

To resolve it - I changed my system variable for platform and it resolved the problem.

Thanks @NickCarlson!

Comment: any idea how the system variable 'Platform' was added in the first place ? Was it visual studio's doing ?

Comment: @littlecegian sorry no idea.

Comment: This environment variable seems to happen because of HP Easy Setup.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Checking this answer, [Why is my Platform environment variable defined as 'BNB'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507856/why-is-my-platform-environment-variable-defined-as-bnb), I have seen that there is a PLATFORM environment variable pointing to BWS.