# Not choosing the right platform by Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 Premium Update 5.

I have a solution with x86 platform activated and on my computer there is a Platform environment variable with value `BWS`.

When I right click on solution and select rebuild I get the following error in all of my projects:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'MyCompany.Data.Environment.Model.csproj'.  Please check to make sure
>   that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and
>   Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='BWS'. 
>   This error may also appear if some other project is trying to follow a
>   project-to-project reference to this project, this project has been
>   unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the referencing
>   project does not build using the same or an equivalent Configuration
>   or Platform.

Why it is getting Platform='BWS' if I have selected 'x86'?

**NOTE**: searching on Internet I have found that this `Platform=BWS` is something specific for HP machines (I'm having this problem on HP workstation). This environment variable is not said by any of my Visual Studio projects, it has been said by HP on all of their computers. Take a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3c4e9c3f-2bf2-436e-80de-e000a7dda8bd/msbuild-and-its-use-of-the-platform-environment-variable?forum=msbuild) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507856/why-is-my-platform-environment-variable-defined-as-bnb).

But, if I use `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86` it compiles without any problem.

I have created another project with Visual Studio and this project compiles perfectly on Visual Studio.

In first's project solution I have found this:

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug MySoftware|Any CPU = Debug MySoftware|Any CPU
    Debug MySoftware|x64 = Debug MySoftware|x64
    Debug MySoftware|x86 = Debug MySoftware|x86
    Debug Plugins|Any CPU = Debug Plugins|Any CPU
    Debug Plugins|x64 = Debug Plugins|x64
    Debug Plugins|x86 = Debug Plugins|x86
    Debug Remote Plugins|Any CPU = Debug Remote Plugins|Any CPU
    Debug Remote Plugins|x64 = Debug Remote Plugins|x64
    Debug Remote Plugins|x86 = Debug Remote Plugins|x86
    Debug SDK|Any CPU = Debug SDK|Any CPU
    Debug SDK|x64 = Debug SDK|x64
    Debug SDK|x86 = Debug SDK|x86
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
    Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    Release|x64 = Release|x64
    Release|x86 = Release|x86
EndGlobalSection
```

There are a lot of configurations. I have remove them but it still doesn't compile and showing the same error.

If I remove `Platform=BWS` environment variable, I don't see that error about `Platform=BWS` but I get another one telling that it doesn't find another solution's project dlls. It seems that Visual Studio doesn't compile any dependant project and only search for their dlls.

I think the problem is that Visual Studio doesn't pass to msbuild platform value (like @stijn has said).

Comment: As far as I know it shouldn't do that (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx etc), but I also cannot reproduce it. Can you check if this happens with a new, clean c# project as well?

Comment: @stijn I have created a console application with its own solution and it works perfectly. But, with the other solution I get the same error about BWS. But, if I use `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86` it compiles without any problem.

Comment: Hard to figure out.. It seems as if VS is not passing 'Platform=x86' explicitly to msbuild, so it uses the environment variable. Do you have anything custom in your build process/files? Like property sheets which you import? Also compare the working project file vs the others in a text editor: there might be something different. Also, you're not alone: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3c4e9c3f-2bf2-436e-80de-e000a7dda8bd/msbuild-and-its-use-of-the-platform-environment-variable?forum=msbuild

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507856/why-is-my-platform-environment-variable-defined-as-bnb

Comment: @stijn I have updated my question. There were custom active solution configurations but I have removed them and I get the same error.

Comment: The "Platform" environment variable acts as an *override* for the VS selection.  You are of course focusing on the wrong problem, the real issue is the *other* project(s) that seem to require a bizarre platform name to compile properly.  Start fixing this issue by deleting the environment variable.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks but I on my question you can read: If I remove Platform=BWS environment variable, I don't see that error but I see another one telling that it doesn't find another solution's project dlls.

Comment: That's what I told you, the *other* project is the problem.  Nobody knows anything about it.  If you don't either then use a telephone to talk the programmer who created it.

Comment: @HansPassant I think you doesn't understand my problem or you didn't read my question carefully. I deleted that variable and the problem is still here. The problem is not that variable, the problem is on that solution. It seems that Visual Studio doesn't pass platform to msbuild: But, if I use msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 it compiles without any problem. All these details are on my question. Please, read it carefully.

Comment: @HansPassant Please, read my question again. I have added more details.